# как убрать "разделители(сепараторы)" из даты или времени в "R"

Tags: r

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть у меня дата и время

дата

```
> head(date)
[1] "31-10-2014" "31-10-2014" "31-10-2014" "31-10-2014" "31-10-2014" "31-10-2014"
```

и время

```
> head(time)
[1] "01:35" "01:45" "01:50" "01:55" "02:00" "02:05"
```

нужно убрать "разделители" чтоб получилось так

в дате убрать "-"

```
> head(date)
[1] "31102014" "31102014" "31102014" "31102014" "31102014" "31102014"
```

в времени убрать ":"

```
> head(time)
[1] "0135" "0145" "0150" "0155" "0200" "0205"
```

а также к времени нужно добавить секунды просто тупо "00" в конце

```
> head(time)
    [1] "013500" "014500" "015000" "015500" "020000" "020500"
```

Comment: Замена "-" на пустую строку и ":" тоже на пустую строку вас определенно спасут по первой части.

Comment: замена где? можете как то более развернуто что ли..

Comment: Замена в строке. Я не специалист по R, поэтому не знаю что там со строковыми функциями.

Comment: я тоже не  специалист потому мне и нужен белее конкретный ответ, желательно кодом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таком случае проще всего использовать `gsub` для замены с `fixed=TRUE` 
( если важна производительность то выиграете чуть на этом)

```
date1="31-10-2014"
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({gsub("-", "",   date1   )},
                               {gsub("-", "",   date1   ,fixed = T)})

Unit: microseconds
                                    expr   min    lq    mean median     uq    max neval
            {     gsub("-", "", date1) } 4.462 5.132 6.40839  5.355 5.8020 33.915   100
 {     gsub("-", "", date1, fixed = T) } 1.338 1.339 2.40999  1.785 2.0085 44.179   100
```

Что бы добавить "00" в конце просто используйте `paste0`

```
time1="01:55"
paste0(gsub(":", "",   time1   ,fixed = T),"00")
```